# How to convert row format data into column format?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example the data looks like this:

```
Name: A
Number: 1
Type: X
Name: B
Number: 2
Type: Y
Name: C
Number: 3
Type: Z
```

And I want to convert it into this format:

```
Name     Number     Type
A         1          X
B         2          Y
C         3          Z
```

Comment: Arrgghhh!  I was typing in a non-VBA answer when this question got closed.  [So I posted it on the other question.](http://superuser.com/a/955845/150988)

Comment: Perhaps a better duplicate: [Transposing data from a single-column list to multiple columns](http://superuser.com/q/831352/354511).

Answer (score 0):

In Excel:

1. Select the data you want to transpose
2. CTRL-C to copy
3. Right click on the cell you want to put the data in
4. Click paste special
5. Check the box that says "Transpose"
6. Click ok.

Reference: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12366/convert-a-row-to-a-column-in-excel-the-easy-way/

Comment: Actually, I don't have just this data, this is what I simplified for you to answer. Actually I have a data exported from active directory, but it's in row format and I need to convert it into excel format.